# 20.04: KDEConnect not working after upgrading from 19.10

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, gnome-shell-extension, 20.04, kde-connect

[image: picture of extension page]

So, GSConnect has been been my most used extension in Ubuntu, but after upgrading to 20.04 stable, it is not working anymore.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Deinstall all gsconnect components
- Install the kdeconnect package by running `sudo apt install kdeconnect`